# How can I dynamically add textbox in a panel in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to dynamically add a textbox/label in a panel. It will be based on an integer (combo box listed). So let's say in the combo box you have chosen  2. In the panel control, there will be two text boxes and labels.

Comment: [Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add). See the (very simplified) example there.

Comment: If you want to add pairs of controls, i.e. one `TextBox` and one `Label`, then it may be worth your while to design a user control that contains that pair and encapsulates all the related functionality.  In your form, you can then add one instance of that user control for each pair.  I would also recommend using a `FlowLayoutPanel` as the container, because it will position its children automatically.  Use the `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of the `Panel` or, if you have other children in the `Panel`, add the `FlowLayoutPanel` to it.

Comment: If you don't want to create your own user control but would rather stick with the pairs of controls, use a `TableLayoutPanel` instead, which will allow you to add the `Labels` in one column and the `TextBoxes` in another, still with automatic positioning.

Comment: thank you very much. i'm going to use Inherit class this time. the add control might not be suitable for my project. i'm going to clone the tabpage and its controls.